# Write a function that takes an array of objects and removes all red-colored foods from the original array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, if-statement

`array, foods = [{ name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Egg', color: 'white' }];`
and here's what I tried,

```
let foods = [{ name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Egg', color: 'white' }];

            function removeRed(food) {
                food.filter(function (x) {
                    if (x.color !== 'red') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return foods;
```

When I call the function like " removeRed(foods) " the output is giving both of the property-value pairs in my array.
I'm a beginner student and this is my first Question here. Hope that someone answers :'D
}

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: The first step when a built-in method doesn't work as "expected" -> Read the documentation: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): _"The `filter()` method **creates a new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function."_

Comment: `filter()` doesn't modify the input, but returns a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put return inside the function before the filter called

```js
function removeRed(food) {
  return food.filter(function (x) {
    if (x.color !== 'red') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Call the function to execute the code

```js
let foods = [{ name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Egg', color: 'white' }];
removeRed(foods); // [{name: 'Egg', color: 'white'}]
```

Best practice Make always the function more generic like this:

```js
function remove(food, color) {
  return food.filter(function (x) {
    if (x.color !== color) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
let foods = [{ name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Egg', color: 'white' }];
remove(foods,'white'); // [{name: 'Apple', color: 'red'}]
```

One line with `ES6+ syntax`:

```js
const remove = (food, color) => food.filter(x=> x.color !== color);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the output of the filter. you were returning the original array

```
function removeRed(food) {
    return food.filter(function (x) {
        if (x.color !== 'red') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank You!! It worked and learned something new!

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close as (obvious) duplicate?

Comment: the new contributor always throws me off, I was being nice @Andreas

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here. I voted to delete now!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to filter non-red items

```
let foods = [{ name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Egg', color: 'white' }];

const filtered = foods.filter(item => item.color !== 'red');

console.log(filtered)
```